# Searching on 3-level structure (in both directions)

Tags: c++, algorithm

[Note] I try to edit your question. Please accept if this is correct. The original question is very ambigous.

I have some task to do. User can input the name of a function and optionally the name of the class and the file. I have to perform some checks on this function name depending upon a check-list. However, the problem is that the checks in the check-list are described for the files, not the functions. i.e, It describes the checks for all the classes and functions appearing in each file. So, when the user enters the function name, I need to map that to the right file and find out the right checks.

Could you please suggest some efficient ways to do this?

**EDIT:** (as simple as I can, sorry my English isn't the best ;))

Let's say we have a application (script?) which one we want to profile (yes! we are creating something like profiler! :D) but we don't want to check everything, just few functions. But there is problem. User of our profiler wants to give list of functions to profile in a little bit strange way.

So, he can give us:
- a name of function - we need to profile every function (or method) which has that name no matter where it is (can be in every file or every class or something like standard library (in this case we don't have file name)).
- a name of class - we need to profile every function/method in this class but class itself can be anywhere in few files (we can have different classes with the same name)
- a name of file - we need to profile everything in this file, but there can be few files with the same name (so in every of them we need to profile every function/method).

And all mix of above, so if we have class (let's call it "Bar") and function ("foo") we need to profile this function "foo" in the class "Bar", but still class can be in any file (there can be few "Bar" classes in few files. If we have file name and function name we need to profile every function which has that name (no matter if it is inside or outside any class) in the file (but still there can be few files with the same name).

Few files or few classes isn't really a problem, because I have already replace execution function in profiler (yes, profiler itself is working) but problem is how to storage names of functions (and classes and files) so it could be as fast as possible (memory doesn't really matter if it fast) to search the function should be profile (in short: execution function ask as about it should profile this function or no and we need to give answer, in execute function we have function name (for sure), class name (if function is method from class) and file name (if function isn't from standard library).

Comment: uhhmmm... I think a small example will help me to understand your problem

Comment: I didn't understand anything..

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like parsing cpp source files, does it?

Comment: Try simplifying the wording of the question by clearly stating what the inputs are and what the outputs should be. As it is, I understood that you get information on (function, class, file) and need to do *something*.

Comment: I added some example for easier understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a xml file to store your check list info. as :

```
<file name="file1"...>
    <class name="class1" ...>
        <func name=" func1" ... />
    </class>
</file>
```

When you run your program, read the xml into memory, each hierarchy build a object and the high hierarchy object include the lower object.
And build three map lists, which the first 'string' is the name of file or class or func, and the second 'object*' is the point to the object built by xml.

When you get an information, you can just use map::find to search it. If you find the 'object1', you can do the method, defined in 'object1' and its including objects.

Comment: Did you purposefully chose the sentences to fit the question? This answer seems very ambigous. e.g What is 'map lists'? map or list? What is 'point to the object'? Did you mean pointer?

Answer (score 0):

You can once go through all your files->classes->functions and create a map (a hash-map) with function name as the key and class and file info as the value.

User enters function name -> you instantly get file/class name by searching your map -> you seek your rules list for the file name and apply the rules.

Comment: I won't work if user gives me only class name (which means that I need to do my job for every function in the class) or file name (like before but for every function in the file and/or every function/method in every class in the file).

Comment: It will work, if you create the same kind of a map for a class name - you'll be able to find it's filename(s) than. And then you can traverse it in forward direction, from class to functions, this is easy.
When user gives you a filename, you can just enumerate all classes and functions inside and do your job. It's not time-consuming, because one file rearly contains too many functions.